# How to export image along with data from same jsp page to excel sheet?

Tags: excel, servlets, jsp-tags

I want to export an image along with some table data from a jsp page to the excel sheet. Please  tell me how to do it?

Now am able to create the image, which is basically a pie chart by using `Google Chart Api`.

But when a user click on the export button the data along with the image should export to excel.
I tried with java POI package but it is not happening.

```
    <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chd=t:<s:property value="assignedTickets"/>,<s:property value="pendingTickets"/>,<s:property value="openedTickets"/>,<s:property value="closedTickets"/>,<s:property value="escalatedTickets"/>&chs=400x225&chl=Assigned|Pending|Opened|Closed|Escalated&chco=00A5C6"/>
```

This is what the url looks like in jsp which is generating a pie chart.

Comment: Post some code of how you're trying to put the image in the Excel with POI. My initial thought is you don't really have an image (not a real image, and not server-side) since Google Chart Api is Javascript (I think) and uses Canvas (maybe), so where are you getting the image?

Comment: Thanks!Please check the url which is generating a pie chart.

Comment: It would be simpler if you separate the problems : on server (through a servlet) generate the Excel file with its data and the pie chart (directly in Excel) via Apache POI and **then** download it.

Comment: @Serge:Thanks!There should be a common button for exporting to excel , so when a user click on that, graph along with table data should export.Now am using display tag for export option. Tell me how to do it with a single click.

Comment: You should say in question that you want to use displaytag export ! I do not know much of it and do not know what it can do : refer to display tag documentation or give elements in question.

Comment: @developerwjk:Thanks!Please check the url which is generating a pie chart